# Swing blurred drag image

Tags: java, image, swing, drag-and-drop

I have a simple task to implement, it works quite ok, but I am facing a very tricky issue regarding custom drag images in Swing. 
The idea behind the task is just to allow the user to perform some DND between a list component and a text component, but during the drag operation to display following the mouse the exact same drawing as the renderer inside the list.

For this I use the cell renderer for the selected elements in the list and paint it over a temporary image. Then send this image to the TransferHandler and everything is fine. The problem is evident when I modify the size of the overall component and make it larger. After a certain extent, the picture that is draw no longer appears correct, but instead it has some gradient applied to it, making the content difficult to read. Following is a snippet of code that reproduces the issue:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.GridLayout;

import javax.swing.DefaultListCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.DefaultListModel;
import javax.swing.DropMode;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class BasicTextListDND {

    private JList<String> makeList() {
        DefaultListModel<String> m = new DefaultListModel<String>();
        for(int i = 0; i<10; i++) {
            m.addElement("Element "+i);            
        }
        JList<String> list = new JList<String>(m);

        list.setTransferHandler(new BasicListTransferHandler());
        list.setDropMode(DropMode.ON_OR_INSERT);
        list.setDragEnabled(true);
        list.setCellRenderer(new DefaultListCellRenderer() {

            /**
             * Comment for <code>serialVersionUID</code>
             */
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            /** {@inheritDoc} */
            public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList<?> list, Object value, int index,
                    boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {
                Component listCellRendererComponent = super.getListCellRendererComponent(list, value, index, isSelected, cellHasFocus);
                if (cellHasFocus == false && isSelected == false) { 
                    if (index % 2 == 0) {
                        listCellRendererComponent.setBackground(Color.RED);
                    } else if (index % 3==0) {
                        listCellRendererComponent.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
                    } else {
                        listCellRendererComponent.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
                    }
                }
                return listCellRendererComponent;
            }

        });
        return list;
    }

    private JTextArea makeTextArea() {
        JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea("Drag here from JList!");
        return textArea;
    }

    public JComponent makeUI() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2,1));
        panel.add(new JScrollPane(makeTextArea()));
        panel.add(new JScrollPane(makeList()));
        return panel;
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        JFrame f = new JFrame("BasicDnD");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        BasicTextListDND app = new BasicTextListDND();
        JComponent appContent = app.makeUI();
        f.setContentPane(appContent);
        f.setSize(600, 320);
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override 
            public void run() { 
                createAndShowGUI(); 
            }
        });
    }
}


/**
 * 
 */
public class BasicListTransferHandler extends TransferHandler {

    /**
     * Comment for <code>serialVersionUID</code>
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override 
    public boolean canImport(TransferHandler.TransferSupport info) {
        if (!info.isDataFlavorSupported(DataFlavor.stringFlavor)) {
            return false;
        }
        JList.DropLocation dl = (JList.DropLocation)info.getDropLocation();
        if (dl.getIndex() == -1) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override 
    public int getSourceActions(JComponent c) {
        BufferedImage dragImage = makeImageFromString(c);
        if (dragImage != null) {
            setDragImage(dragImage);            
            Point mousePosition = c.getMousePosition();
            if (mousePosition != null) {
                setDragImageOffset(mousePosition);
            }
        }
        return COPY;
    }

    private final JPanel tempDrawPanel = new JPanel();

    private BufferedImage createDragImage(JList<String> list) {
        int width = 0;
        int height = 0;
        int[] selectedIndices = list.getSelectedIndices();
        for(int i =0; i<selectedIndices.length; i++){
            int idx = selectedIndices[i];
            Rectangle cellBounds = list.getCellBounds(idx, idx);
            height += cellBounds.height;
            width = Math.max(width, cellBounds.width); // we want to create a drag image as big as the largest cell
        }
        BufferedImage br = null;
        if (width > 0 && height > 0) {
            br = list.getGraphicsConfiguration().createCompatibleImage(width, height, Transparency.TRANSLUCENT);
        }
        return br;
    }

    private BufferedImage makeImageFromString(JComponent src) {
        JList<String> sourceList = (JList<String>)src;
        BufferedImage  br = createDragImage(sourceList);
        if (br != null) {
            int[] selectedIndices = sourceList.getSelectedIndices();            
            int yD = 0;
            Graphics g = br.getGraphics();
            try{
                for(int idx: selectedIndices) {
                    ListCellRenderer<? super String> cellRenderer = sourceList.getCellRenderer();
                    String valueAt = sourceList.getModel().getElementAt(idx);
                    Component c = cellRenderer.getListCellRendererComponent(sourceList, valueAt, idx, false, false);
                    Rectangle itemCellBounds = sourceList.getCellBounds(idx, idx);                
                    SwingUtilities.paintComponent(g, c, tempDrawPanel, itemCellBounds.x, yD, itemCellBounds.width, itemCellBounds.height);
                    yD = itemCellBounds.y+itemCellBounds.height;
                }
            }finally {
                g.dispose();
            }
            br.coerceData(true);
        }
        return br;
    }

    @Override 
    protected Transferable createTransferable(JComponent c) {
        JList<String> list = (JList<String>)c;
        List<String> selectedValuesList = list.getSelectedValuesList();                
        StringBuffer buff = new StringBuffer();
        for (int i = 0; i < selectedValuesList.size(); i++) {
            String val = selectedValuesList.get(i);
            buff.append(val == null ? "" : val.toString());
            if (i != selectedValuesList.size()- 1) {
                buff.append("\n");
            }
        }
        return new StringSelection(buff.toString());
    }
}
```

The problem lies, I think, somewhere in the makeImageFromString method, but after 2 days of digging through Swing/AWT libraries and understanding how the drag image is drawn, I still fail to fix this issue. The bottom-line question: is there any obscure logic in AWT that applies this gradient if the drag image is over a certain size?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Marius.

Comment: On an (even) stranger note, I wanted to see exactly what is the size that messes up the drawing, and I found that when the component exceeds 300 px, the dragged image is blurred. Does anybody know if this value holds any special meaning to Swing DND mechanism?

Comment: Comming back to this issue, does anybody know if maybe there is a workaround for using the dragImage functionality in TransferHandler, as opposed to the working solution (proposed by aterai) of display a separate window where the drag image is displayed? I am wondering if we should really reimplement the drag image functionality....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about translates the origin of the graphics context:

```
//SwingUtilities.paintComponent(g, c, tempDrawPanel, itemCellBounds.x, yD, itemCellBounds.width, itemCellBounds.height);
//yD = itemCellBounds.y+itemCellBounds.height;
SwingUtilities.paintComponent(g, c, tempDrawPanel, 0, 0, itemCellBounds.width, itemCellBounds.height);
g.translate(0, itemCellBounds.height);
```

**Edit:**

@user3619696: I misunderstood.

I would guess that the "blurred drag image" opacity depend on the Windows desktop theme. So try using translucent `JWindow` instead of `TransferHandler#setDragImage(...)`.

[image]

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.datatransfer.*;
import java.awt.dnd.*;
import java.awt.image.*;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.*;

public class BasicTextListDND2 {

    private JList<String> makeList() {
        DefaultListModel<String> m = new DefaultListModel<String>();
        for(int i = 0; i<10; i++) {
            m.addElement("Element "+i);
        }
        JList<String> list = new JList<String>(m);

        list.setTransferHandler(new BasicListTransferHandler());
        list.setDropMode(DropMode.ON_OR_INSERT);
        list.setDragEnabled(true);
        list.setCellRenderer(new DefaultListCellRenderer() {

            /**
             * Comment for <code>serialVersionUID</code>
             */
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            /** {@inheritDoc} */
            public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList<?> list, Object value, int index,
                    boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {
                Component listCellRendererComponent = super.getListCellRendererComponent(list, value, index, isSelected, cellHasFocus);
                if (cellHasFocus == false && isSelected == false) { 
                    if (index % 2 == 0) {
                        listCellRendererComponent.setBackground(Color.RED);
                    } else if (index % 3==0) {
                        listCellRendererComponent.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
                    } else {
                        listCellRendererComponent.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
                    }
                }
                return listCellRendererComponent;
            }

        });
        return list;
    }

    private JTextArea makeTextArea() {
        JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea("Drag here from JList!");
        return textArea;
    }

    public JComponent makeUI() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2,1));
        panel.add(new JScrollPane(makeTextArea()));
        panel.add(new JScrollPane(makeList()));
        return panel;
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        JFrame f = new JFrame("BasicDnD");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        BasicTextListDND2 app = new BasicTextListDND2();
        JComponent appContent = app.makeUI();
        f.setContentPane(appContent);
        f.setSize(600, 320);
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override 
            public void run() { 
                createAndShowGUI(); 
            }
        });
    }
}


/**
 * 
 */
class BasicListTransferHandler extends TransferHandler {

    /**
     * Comment for <code>serialVersionUID</code>
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private final JLabel label = new JLabel() {
        @Override public boolean contains(int x, int y) {
            return false;
        }
    };
    private final JWindow window = new JWindow();
    public BasicListTransferHandler() {
        super();
        window.add(label);
        //window.setBackground(new Color(0, true));
        window.setOpacity(.8f);
        DragSource.getDefaultDragSource().addDragSourceMotionListener(new DragSourceMotionListener() {
            @Override public void dragMouseMoved(DragSourceDragEvent dsde) {
                Point pt = dsde.getLocation();
                pt.translate(10, 10); // offset
                if (!window.isVisible()) {
                    window.setVisible(true);
                }
                window.setLocation(pt);
            }
        });
    }
    @Override protected void exportDone(JComponent c, Transferable data, int action) {
        super.exportDone(c, data, action);
        window.setVisible(false);
    }

    @Override 
    public boolean canImport(TransferHandler.TransferSupport info) {
        if (!info.isDataFlavorSupported(DataFlavor.stringFlavor)) {
            return false;
        }
        JList.DropLocation dl = (JList.DropLocation)info.getDropLocation();
        if (dl.getIndex() == -1) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override 
    public int getSourceActions(JComponent c) {
        BufferedImage dragImage = makeImageFromString(c);
        if (dragImage != null) {
            //setDragImage(dragImage);            
            //Point mousePosition = c.getMousePosition();
            //if (mousePosition != null) {
            //    setDragImageOffset(mousePosition);
            //}
            label.setIcon(new ImageIcon(dragImage));
            window.setLocation(-2000, -2000);
            window.pack();
        }
        return COPY;
    }

    private final JPanel tempDrawPanel = new JPanel();

    private BufferedImage createDragImage(JList<String> list) {
        int width = 0;
        int height = 0;
        int[] selectedIndices = list.getSelectedIndices();
        for(int i =0; i<selectedIndices.length; i++){
            int idx = selectedIndices[i];
            Rectangle cellBounds = list.getCellBounds(idx, idx);
            height += cellBounds.height;
            width = Math.max(width, cellBounds.width); // we want to create a drag image as big as the largest cell
        }
        BufferedImage br = null;
        if (width > 0 && height > 0) {
            br = list.getGraphicsConfiguration().createCompatibleImage(width, height, Transparency.TRANSLUCENT);
        }
        return br;
    }

    private BufferedImage makeImageFromString(JComponent src) {
        JList<String> sourceList = (JList<String>)src;
        BufferedImage br = createDragImage(sourceList);
        if (br != null) {
            int[] selectedIndices = sourceList.getSelectedIndices();
            int yD = 0;
            Graphics g = br.getGraphics();
            try{
                for(int idx: selectedIndices) {
                    ListCellRenderer<? super String> cellRenderer = sourceList.getCellRenderer();
                    String valueAt = sourceList.getModel().getElementAt(idx);
                    Component c = cellRenderer.getListCellRendererComponent(sourceList, valueAt, idx, false, false);
                    Rectangle itemCellBounds = sourceList.getCellBounds(idx, idx);
                    //SwingUtilities.paintComponent(g, c, tempDrawPanel, itemCellBounds.x, itemCellBounds.y + yD, itemCellBounds.width, itemCellBounds.height);
                    //yD = itemCellBounds.y+itemCellBounds.height;
                    SwingUtilities.paintComponent(g, c, tempDrawPanel, 0, 0, itemCellBounds.width, itemCellBounds.height);
                    g.translate(0, itemCellBounds.height);
                }
            }finally {
                g.dispose();
            }
            br.coerceData(true);
        }
        return br;
    }

    @Override 
    protected Transferable createTransferable(JComponent c) {
        JList<String> list = (JList<String>)c;
        List<String> selectedValuesList = list.getSelectedValuesList();
        StringBuffer buff = new StringBuffer();
        for (int i = 0; i < selectedValuesList.size(); i++) {
            String val = selectedValuesList.get(i);
            buff.append(val == null ? "" : val.toString());
            if (i != selectedValuesList.size()- 1) {
                buff.append("\n");
            }
        }
        return new StringSelection(buff.toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Unforturnately, that does not solve the problem. The dragged image is still blured if the size of the component is larger. Nevertheless, thanks for the hint as it uses the swing API to translate the drawing coordinates (so I do not have to use the locla variable to memorize the new origin)

Comment: Wow, great! I think your second approach is the best. At least it works in my test case. So, in the end, it does appear that windows (or at least swing APIs) tinkers with the dragged image if it is bigger than a certain width. Nevertheless, thank you very much, you have given me a clear way out of this mess :).